# How to suppress “Name:” and underline in eqexam on pages 2 and following

Tags: acrotex

I would like to have the Name:_______ part on the first page only, but not on the following pages.

In the following MWE I would like to not have the Name:_____ on the second page and following. Does anyone know a solution?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[myconfig,nosolutions,pointsonright,totalsonright,noparttotals]{eqexam}

\title[T1]{Semestertest}
\author{John Doe}
\subject[FDPH]{FD Physics I}
\date{Spring 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{exam}[Teil 1]{Part1}

\begin{instructions}[Teil 1]
Instructions\dots
\end{instructions}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[5]
Problem

\begin{solution}[.5in]
Solution
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the source at http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/eqexam/eqexam.dtx.

> \DescribeMacro{\examNameLabel} provides a line for the student to
>   enter his/her name into the exam. The command \cs{examNameLabel} can
>   be used to define the name label, the default is \texttt{Name:}

Since "Name:" is typeset while `\output` is active, macro `\c@page` (which outputs the current page number) gives the correct value in all instances. I suspect adding the line

```
 \makeatletter\examNameLabel{\ifnum\c@page=\@ne Name:\fi}\makeatother
```

to your document, will suffice. This does not get rid of the `\hline` underneath, though, but you have not specified whether you want to keep that.

If you also want to get rid of the line on all subsequent pages, you will need to add the lines

```
\makeatletter
\examNameLabel{\ifnum\c@page=\@ne Name:\fi}
\eqExamName[\Ff\FfRequired]{\ifnum\c@page=\@ne2.25in\else\z@\fi}
\rheadeqe{\ifnum\c@page>\@ne\vrule\@width2.25in\@height\z@\@depth\z@\fi}
\makeatother
```

which also retains original spacing. A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[myconfig,nosolutions,pointsonright,totalsonright,noparttotals]{eqexam}

\makeatletter
\examNameLabel{\ifnum\c@page=\@ne Name:\fi}
\eqExamName[\Ff\FfRequired]{\ifnum\c@page=\@ne2.25in\else\z@\fi}
\rheadeqe{\ifnum\c@page>\@ne\vrule\@width2.25in\@height\z@\@depth\z@\fi}
\makeatother

\title[T1]{Semestertest}
\author{John Doe}
\subject[FDPH]{FD Physics I}
\date{Spring 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{exam}[Teil 1]{Part1}

\begin{instructions}[Teil 1]
Instructions\dots
\end{instructions}

\newpage

\begin{problem}[5]
Problem

\begin{solution}[.5in]
Solution
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

You can check the spacing by commenting and uncommenting the added code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works very well, and what's more I learned about variables like \@ne == 1 ! 
I have to admit that I don't understand all the finesses of you code, only that it checks if the header of page one is rendered or not.